# GraphQl pass query arguments down to sub type

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have a query named ProfileQuery:

```
const ProfileQuery = {
  description: 'Profile',
  type: UserType,
  args: {
    argOne: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
  },
  resolve: (
    root
  ) => getProfile(),
```

I have a type named: **UserType** and I want to be able to access the arguments in a sub type of this.

```
UserType -> SettingsType.requiresVerification
```

I have the following field in the **UserType**:

```
settings: {
  type: SettingsType, // I want to access the args from the Profile query in here?!
  resolve: async (
     requestedUser,
     args,
     { rootValue: { request: { user } } }
   ) => getAllSettings(user.id),
},
```

However when I log the args inside the **SettingsType**, they are empty.

How can I pass the arguments down from the ProfileQuery to the SettingsType?

Answer (score 0):

I searched quite a while for this and I cannot find a default way to solve this. My solution for now is that I attached the args to the parent.

This is an example, where you would retrieve a user and list of messages, and apply and offset and limit to your list of messages:

```
Query: {
  user: async (parent, { id, offset, limit }, { models }) => {
    const user = await models.User.findByPk(id);
    user.offset = offset;    // Attach arg here
    user.limit = limit;      // Attach arg here
    return user;
  },
},

User: {
  messages: async (user, args, { models }) => {

    return await models.Message.findAll({
      offset: user.offset,   // Retrieve arg here
      limit: user.limit,     // Retrieve arg here
      where: {
        userId: user.id,
      },
    });
  },
}
```

Syntax is not exactly like yours but you get the idea. And there should be additional checks on wether those properties exist. A bit surprised there is not a simple way to do this (or, at least, a visually simpler way)!

Hope this helps other peeps!